# Component does not stop nested dependencies

Tags: clojure, components

I bumped into a following problem while using the [component](https://github.com/stuartsierra/component) library - whenever a given component depends on another, the associated dependency in the system map does not release it's resources (i.e. is not stopped) on 'stop-system'.

I would assume that both lifecycle methods work in the dependency order and call start / stop for each component and its dependencies in a tree traversal of the dependency graph.

I haven't yet looked in detail, but I made a simple application that reproduces the problem in a simple unit test (call `lein test`):

https://github.com/fbielejec/component-app

Answer (score 2):

The reason your test fails is because you retrieve the database dependency from the `:message-handlers`, instead of the database dependency directly.  As you indicate yourself, the `stop` function of the database is correctly invoked, so the resource would be released (in a real-life situation).

However, the database dependency of the message handler still refers to the *old* database.  Due to the nature of immutability, that's not the same instance of the one that is the result of the `stop` function.

If you were to write the test like this, it would work:

```
(is (nil? (-> the-system
              system/start
              system/stop
              :database
              :connection)))
```

This verification succeeds as expected.

I hope this answers your question?

Comment: I understand that the database component is stopped, which effectively would close the connection and release it - I believe however that the dependencies should also be cleaned during the tree traversal, otherwise it *seems* like they are not released. In another words I would expect the stop to be a complement of a start lifecycle method.

Comment: I haven't had the need for something like that.  In any case, that's a change that should be implemented in the component library itself.  I guess it could be modified so that it re-binds the dependencies on stop, just like on start.  But since you're stopping everything, why bother? :-)

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, if you add `printlns` to the start and stop methods you will see this:

On `system/start`:

```
db start
message handler start
```

On `system/stop`:

```
message handler stop
db stop
```

I don't know why the database reference in the message handler isn't updated.